# How to check if optional class argument is supplied or not?

Tags: c++

Say I have this struct

```
struct float2 {
    float x;
    float y;
}
```

and then there is some constructor somewhere

```
struct constructable {
    constructable(float2 opt = float2()) {
        if (opt == float2()) { //doesn't work
            //fill out opt with default values
        }
    }
}
```

How do I check whether or not something was passed through opt?

Comment: Have two constructors: constructable() and constructable(float /*not optionale*/)

Comment: `opt == float2()` You need something like `bool operator ==(const float2& m, const float2& n) { return m.x == n.x && m.y == n.y; }` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
struct constructable {
    constructable(float2 opt = float2()) {
        if (opt == float2()) { //doesn't work
            //fill out opt with default values
        }
    }
};
```

if the desired default values are known at compile time then just do

```
struct constructable {
    constructable(float2 opt = {2.72, 3.14} ) {
    }
};
```

Otherwise use two constructors:

```
struct constructable {
    constructable() {
        // Use whatever computed values
    }
    constructable(float2 o) {
        // Use o
    }
};
```